# WinError 5 when attempting to run JS from Sublime Text

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext3

I've implemented a JavaScript console into Sublime Text 3 using node.js.

Build code (saved as `Node.sublime-build`):

```
{
"cmd": ["node /Program Files/nodejs", "$file"],
"selector": "source.js"
}
```

It originally gave `WinError 2` which meant it couldn't find node.js. I fixed that by adding the file location.

---

Now, it gives `[WinError 5] Access is denied`. Doing some research, I discovered the solution of "Run as Administrator". Unfortunately, that didn't work.

My JavaScript is perfectly valid and node.js has been installed.

What is the problem? Do I have to reinstall node.js with the permission to connect to my PATH? (I deselected that during installation)

Comment: If I remember correctly, you need to separate each item in the command into array items, like so: `["node", "/Program Files/nodejs", "$file"]`. Also, why have you not specified the drive (e.g. `C:/`)? I also believe you have to escape space characters in unquoted arguments, like `/Program\ Files/`.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I have tried a combination of your solutions, but they all return `WinError 2` which is solved in my version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in the installation of node.js.

In my original installation, I unchecked `Implement into command line` (or something similar) which didn't allow it to "plant" itself into my system.

I reinstalled node.js with that option checked and it works now!